# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException error while calling Java API from .NET

Tags: java, .net, sockets, exception, websocket

Hope you are doing well. Basically I am calling Java API from .NET .
Most of the time it is working absolutely fine but the thing it sometimes once or twice in a day it gives me Socket exception. I am putting down the calling code and the exception stack trace. Any suggestion to fix this once and for all will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.!!

Code :

```
 var client = new HttpClient{Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettingsConfiguration.GetConfig<string>("appSettings:Generic"))};
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", AppSettingsConfiguration.GetConfig<string>("appSettings:JavaAPIKey"));
 var response = client.PostAsync(AppSettingsConfiguration.GetConfig<string>("appSettings:Generic"), new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Stack Trace :

```
Error reported : One or more errors occurred. Inner Exception 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did 
not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond {IP} at 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, 
Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner 
exception stack trace --- Stack trace :
```

Comment: Ping Pong should do it. My guess is that connection is severed after a certain amount of time. So by adding a ping pong between servers every minute you should keep the connection open. Try googling it -> "How to use websocket ping pong"

Comment: sockets are inherently unreliable; this is normal and does not represent an error